# Getting NULL Value in Stored Procedure TEXT Column

Tags: db2

Below Query, I am using to get the SP definition but in `TEXT column` I am getting as `NULL` Value in `IBM DATA Studio` but I am able to `CALL` the SP.

```
SELECT PROCNAME, TEXT FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME LIKE '%USP_ABC%'
```

Please Help

Comment: The stored-procedure might not be SQL. What is in the LANGUAGE column ? Also the TEXT column is a CLOB , so the *tool* that you are using to submit the SQL has to be able to display those - if in doubt use SUBSTR(TEXT, 1, 1024) for example to extract from the clob.

Comment: LANGUAGE is SQL only and for other SPs, I am able to see the TEXT Filed value Except for the USP_ABC it might be because of length. But using SUBSTR(TEXT, 1, 1024) I got he Substring part of the SP

Comment: you could use `db2look` to dump you stored procedure DDL, or just browse in Data Studio and generate DDL from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have confirmed that the syscat.procedures.language is SQL, and that your query-tool is able to display a substr() of the text.

Workaround depends on the length(text) of the row of interest:

```
SELECT PROCNAME, substr(TEXT,1, 1024) FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME LIKE '%USP_ABC%'
```

You may need to adjust the length of the substr extract depending on the length of the text and your configuration.  For example substr(TEXT, 1, 2048 ) or a higher value for the length as necessary that your query-tool can cope with.

You can find the length of the text column with the LENGTH(TEXT) for the row of interest.

You can also CAST a CLOB to char or varchar to a length that fits within their limits and whatever query tool limitations you have.
Another option is to use a *different* query tool that can work with CLOB.

Comment: But it is not giving the complete SP Code

Comment: I tried SUBSTR(TEXT,17,1024) till Start point 17 it is working after that SUBSTR(TEXT,18,1024) is not working

Comment: substr(text, 1, 1040) is working when I am increasing the length value 1041 it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of Data Studio with the latest fix?  It sounds like you might have an invalid UTF-8 character in you SP, or as you are using SUBSTR and SUBSTRING you are breaking a mulit-byte character in two.

You could try setting

```
-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3
```

in your eclipse.ini   to get Java to use a replacment character rather than replace the invalid string with nul

See this tech note

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684365

Otherwise, do raise this with IBM Suppport